# How to initialize FirebaseRecyclerOptions with Generic typed Class as Model1<Model2> in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, generics, firebase-realtime-database

> This is the main class that has a generic type:

```
public class MainClass<T extends MainClass>{

 //one of the parameters
 private TypeClass mType;
  
 //parameters

}
```

> This is the second class that be used for generic type to Main Class

```
public class TypeClass extends MainClass{

 //parameters

}
```

> And This is what I want to do, in onCreatView in MainActivity:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()    

FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Hesaplar>()
            .setQuery(query,MainClass<TypeClass>.class)
            .build();

recyclerView.setAdapter(new ExampleRecycViewAdapter(options));
```

> As you know, normally this `.setQuery` method is used as `.setQuery(query,MainClass.class)`
>
> But I coundt handle using `.setQuery` method as `.setQuery(query,MainClass<TypeClass>.class)`
>
> **Because I need the object of   `mMain : MainClass<TypeClass>`**
>
> **Could you help me?**

(By the way, I'm sorry for my English, I hope I explained my issue)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't really matter if your `MainClass` class is generic or not, when you are setting a Query, simply use:

```
.setQuery(query, MainClass.class)
```

And the compiler will always know how your class is defined.